# Offline installer IE 8?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

I need an offline installer for Internet Explorer 8.

I've downloaded one setup that's 16MB. However when opening it, it asks to download updates - the problem is my Internet connection is very slow so the installation will take a very long time.

Is there a standalone offline installer for Windows XP that doesn't need to download in this way?

Comment: Disconnect from the internet during Install, what happens?

Comment: With Internet Explorer 7, 8, and 9 it should ask if you want to install updates as part of the installation process. If you select NO, will it still ask you to connect to the internet for updates?

Comment: @kobaltz first I installed the IE 7 and then I go for IE 8 and unchecked the install updates then the setup complete. But before installing IE 7 I did the same but it doesn't install and say for check updates. Thanks for your help. I didn't face this problem before.

Comment: I've installed that 16 MB offline installer for Windows XP and it did not require an internet connection. It's possible that IE8 has some other windows update dependencies that it is first trying to install. This is what you'll want to look into. I'd suggest to first install service pack 3 of XP if you don't already have it installed and then try the IE8 offline installer. Also post the link from where you downloaded your offline installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc817415.aspx

Internet Explorer Admin Kit. Allows you to install custom images of IE.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Technet subscription : [Click Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/subscriptions/downloads/default.aspx?pv=36:342).

If you have a MSDN subscription : [Click Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/default.aspx?pv=18:370).

IF you don't have a subscription : [Click Here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/internet-explorer/downloads/ie-8).

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be what you're looking for:

> http://www.johnnychin.com/blog/2009/05/ie8-standalone-installer/